# How To Get The Webcam To Record From Guitar Rig Directly

Tags: recording

i am trying to figure out how to get my webcam to record directly from Guiat Rig. Currently i have to manualy sync the audio and video.
i have the focusrite scarlet 2i2 audio interface. If possible i don't want to use a mic. 
When i see the recording sources in webcam I see either the laptop mic or the line in from focusrite audio interface. I choose line in from focusrite. The guitar recording happens but the effects from guitar rig don't get recorded.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focusrite scarlet 2i2 has no inbuilt mic, you need to connect an "external mic" to it, or connect the guitar lineout to it. If you have effects pedals, just connect the last 1/4" connector n the chain to the input of the Focusrite.

Please update why you are having sync problems. Anyway don't not rely on a webcam to give synced audio/video. I would say that if you record video & audio from different sources, almost always you have to sync audio with video. Professional gear have a "sync clock" that makes it automatic but this is expensive. At less expensive level you have to work "hard sometimes" with sync. Having a good program like Final Cut Pro or Adobe Premiere helps.

Apart from the discussion of how to fix **[this](http://www.zoom.co.jp/products/q3hd/)** (Zoom Q3HD Video Recorder) to the guitar, this is a very practical audio/video recorder, you can even connect external input to it.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, Something has just got me worried a little and this is offtopic from this thread but , i have bought the focusrite audio interface and worried that there may be some issue with the bass. I connect the left right out from  focusrite to a Y connector and connect this to 2.1 speakers I find that the woofer is not producing any bass. The focusrite also has a headphone out at front but i am not sure if a headphone out can be connected to a 2.1 speaker or not. If it can be i would like to check the bass by connecting it to the 2.1 speakers to check if Y connector is at fault

Comment: @silverkid, a cable cannot cut out just some frequencies. So if any sound comes thru to the speakers, the cable is working. Veeeery tiny changes in tone you can improve with better cables but not the whole bass disappearing. I would connect like you do, you can also connect to the phones if you want. I would say your problem is in the 2.1 speaker, check for a bass volume knob, they often have to be able to calibrate/adjust the proportion of bass in the whole sound from the 2.1 system. Post the model and we can be more specific.

Comment: did 2 things - 1. connected the 2.1 speakers to android phone - woofers are fine. 2 - connected the headphone out of focusrite to 2.1 speakers to check the bass again bass and woofers are fine. so the problem of base has to be either left right out or the Y connector. I am using audio drivers of focusrite. which has a control panel with buffer setting which can be increased or decreased . thats all no other settings

Comment: @silverkid, what audio software do you use for the focusrite? is there a mixer or a EQ function?

Comment: I am using audio drivers of focusrite. which has a control panel with buffer setting which can be increased or decreased . thats all no other settings

Comment: @silverkid, maybe an eq in your OS? By the way, is it focusrite drivers running or OS's drivers?

Comment: its the focusrite drivers. Problem Fixed. Sergio surprisingly the poor quality cables and connectors were causing the problem. A direct cable fixed it. i think i was making unnecessary joints.